# Will it be possible for PowerShell to passing value across to Lua

Tags: powershell, lua

I'm new in PowerShell and Lua, just wandering will it be possible for PowerShell to passing value across to Lua ?

Example, I have a PowerShell will read through a csv file records and I would like to pass the id from the csv to Lua. Will it be possible and how?

Answer (score 3):

Lua scripts can use command line arguments in the form of the top level vararg operator `...`. Here's an example:

**test.lua**

```lua
local a, b, c = ...
print('a', a)
print('b', b)
print('c', c)
```

**On command line:**

```sh
lua test.lua 1 2 3
```

**Output:**

```
a       1
b       2
c       3
```

So, in your powershell script, replace `test.lua` with your script, and the `1 2 3` with the CSV ID.

I've tried looking for a good resource for more info on how `...` works, but I can't seem to find any. If anyone knows of one, let me know, or suggest an edit, thanks.

Comment: `arg` is deprecated last I checked, though I guess it depends on your lua version/implementation.

Comment: You're confusing the local `arg` table automatically created for vararg functions in old versions of Lua and the global `arg` table created by the command line interpreter, which is still supported.

Comment: Yeah, arg does _work_, but I'm not a fan of using it, e.g., if I want my own variable with the same name. Is it a good name? Probably not, but implicit globals are kinda nasty anyway.